# Unexpected 10px margin when using float in css

Tags: css, css-float

I faced with issue using property "float" in CSS.
On the top of the page occurs 10px margin.
How to fix it?

PS.Adding empty div to parent div with id="background1" doesn't work
Also I read this article https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ but don't get how to apply those Techniques for Clearing Floats

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#background1 {
    background: #F6F7FB;
    width: 100%;
    height: 527px;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
}

/*Header menu*/

#background1 li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline;
}
#background1 li a {
    font-family: HalisGR-Medium;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3B3B3B;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 52px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}
#navmenu {
    margin-right: 72px;
}
/*Header menu ends*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Header menu-->
    <div id="background1" style="clear: both">
       <div style="clear: both;"></div>
           <section id="navmenu">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
           </section>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't because of the floated children. Just apply `margin:0;` to the `ul`. The `margin-top` is what's collapsing and showing outside of the parent.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#background1 {
    background: #F6F7FB;
    width: 100%;
    height: 527px;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
}

/*Header menu*/

#background1 li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline;
}
#background1 li a {
    font-family: HalisGR-Medium;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3B3B3B;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 52px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}
#navmenu {
    margin-right: 72px;
}
#navmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
}
/*Header menu ends*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Header menu-->
    <div id="background1" style="clear: both">
       <div style="clear: both;"></div>
           <section id="navmenu">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
           </section>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It looks so simple, how I didn't understand it myself.
But why its margin by default has this value?

Comment: @DimaKononenko no problem. It's so that you don't have to write CSS for elements to have default style that looks decent. Just like `ul`'s have default left-padding so that the list is indented. `p`'s and headings (`h1`, `h2`, etc) have default margins, and `h1`, `h2`, etc have bigger font size so that you can just write HTML and the page will lay out in a readable, expected format. This is also why, if you do a lot of CSS work, you should look in to normalize.css or a reset stylesheeet to remove all that stuff so that these things don't surprise you and affect your layout.